# SQLiteException near "<" while delete query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, where-clause

I am trying to delete a few rows from my SQLite database like this:

```
dbUtilsObj.delete(EngineUtiReport.TABLE_NAME, 
    EngineUtiReport.Columns.KEY_ENGINE_UTI_UNIX_TIME + DBUtils.IS_LESS_THAN,
    new String[] { String.valueOf(nDaysOldUnixTime) });
```

In the above code `nDayOldTimeInMills = 1429963811949` and `DBUtils.IS_LESS_THAN = " < "`.

But I am getting this syntax error exception and I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "<": syntax error (code 1): , 
while compiling: DELETE FROM engine_utilization_report WHERE unix_time <
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:686)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using parameterised queries you need to specify where you want the parameters to be inserted into your query. You do this by adding a `?` where the parameter is supposed to go. Now look at the query in the exception and it becomes pretty obvious what is wrong:

```
DELETE FROM engine_utilization_report WHERE unix_time <
```

Notice the `unix_time <` at the end? The `?` is missing. The correct query should look like this:

```
DELETE FROM engine_utilization_report WHERE unix_time < ?
```

To fix the error you just need to add the `?` at the end of the where clause like this:

```
dbUtilsObj.delete(EngineUtiReport.TABLE_NAME, 
    EngineUtiReport.Columns.KEY_ENGINE_UTI_UNIX_TIME + DBUtils.IS_LESS_THAN + "?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(nDaysOldUnixTime) });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
dbUtilsObj.delete(EngineUtiReport.TABLE_NAME, 
    EngineUtiReport.Columns.KEY_ENGINE_UTI_UNIX_TIME + DBUtils.IS_LESS_THAN + "?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(nDaysOldUnixTime) });
```

When you are passing an argument to the delete query you need to indicate where that argument is supposed to be placed with a `?`. In your case that is at the very end of the where clause.